# css translate doesn't work with Math functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to translate 4 rectangular boxes to with sin/cos function. But it doesn't work in chrome/firefox. However in IE, it works. Given below is the code and the you can see the demo in [jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/6h8GD/7/)

```
(function() {
    var circle = $(".circle"),
        circleChild = $(".circle-child", circle),
        circleChildLength = circleChild.find("li").length,
        isDragged = false,
        speed = 5,
        angles = [],
        initialDistance = 0,
        totalDistance = 150;

    function moveChildCircles() {
        initialDistance += speed;
        if(initialDistance >= totalDistance  || initialDistance <= 0) {
            speed = -speed; 
            isDragged = !isDragged;
        }

      /* This doesn't work, it works only when I set either translateX or translateY     (not both). */

        circleChild.find("li").each(function(i) {
            $(this).css("transform", "translate(" + initialDistance*Math.cos(angles[i]) + "px," + initialDistance*Math.sin(angles[i]) + "px)");
        });
    }

    circle.click(function() {
        var addAngle = Math.PI*2/circleChildLength;

        for(var i = 0; i < circleChildLength; i++) {
            angles[i] = i*addAngle;
        }   
        isDragged = !isDragged;
    });



    (function animate() {

        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        if(isDragged) {
            moveChildCircles();
        }
    }());

}());
```

As you can see this works only for either one of translateX/translateY. When I debug this, 
animate() method update only first li value. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the CSS change wasn't working due to the math evaluating to fractional pixels. Try using `Math.round` on your pixel calculation:

```
$(this).css("transform", "translate(" + Math.round(initialDistance*Math.cos(angles[i])) + "px," + Math.round(initialDistance*Math.sin(angles[i])) + "px)");
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/6h8GD/3/)

Comment: I came up with the same answer, but used Math.floor().

Comment: We should probably split the difference and use `Math.round()`.

Comment: oh man, you are awesome. I do this in html5 canvas and it works there. But when I done using DOM, browser simply ignore it. It means css translate doesn't support fractions.

Comment: And by the way, I think we can use toFixed() also